# Why is it recommended that SQL Server not be run on the domain contoller in an SBS 2008 system?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, dhcp, domain-controller, windows-sbs-2008

We are building up our SBS 2008 R2 server and had in mind to put an SQL Server on the same box, same system.  First uses of the system are a local file server, VPN for the same purpose, and a central database location.  So far we are only a file server.

SBS 2008 (as noted elsewhere) WANTS to be the domain controller, so we turned off DHCP on our router.  The system check performed before doing the SQL Server install complains about DHCP running on the same server.  MS articles say that is for securtiy reasons.

So what kind of security danger would we risk, and what is the simplest way to keep everything happy?

Answer (score 0):

Does the system check "prevent" you from installing SQL, or is it just a warning? Are you trying to install SQL Server from the SBS media, or from a different SKU? If so, which one?

If you have SBS Premium, SQL is part of the installed (or available) features.

Also, SBS is expecting to be the DC, but you don't have to make it the DHCP server - although if you're into the "manage it all from one console" it makes sense to have them on one box.

Answer (score 0):

The security angle is simply that by isolating services from one another (separate physical boxes) one compromised service couldn't be use to compromise other services on the the same server.  Presumably your risk assessment has asked (and attempted to answer) the impact of your SBS 2008 server being compromised.  If there is no budget (or desire) for separate hardware, perhaps there is budget for documenting threats, their possible impacts, awhat kind of recovery time your organization can afford, and necessary recovery steps.